# Matrix dimension must agree error in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have adapted some existing code for my program but I am coming across an error that I do not know the cause for. I have data with N observations where my goal is to break up the data into increasing smaller subsamples and do calculations on each of the subsamples. To determine the how the subsample size will change, the program finds divisors of N and stores it into an array OptN.

```
dmin = 2;
% Find  OptN such that it has the largest number of 
% divisors among all natural numbers in the interval [0.99*N,N] 
N = length(x); 
N0 = floor(0.99*N);
dv = zeros(N-N0+1,1);
for i = N0:N,
    dv(i-N0+1) = length(divisors(i,dmin));
end
OptN = N0 + find(max(dv)==dv) - 1;
% Use the first OptN values of x for further analysis
x = x(1:OptN);
% Find the divisors >= dmin for OptN
d = divisors(OptN,dmin);  

function d = divisors(n,n0)
% Find all divisors of the natural number N greater or equal to N0
i = n0:floor(n/2);
d = find((n./i)==floor(n./i))' + n0 - 1; % Problem line
```

In function divisors is where the problem occurs. I have 'Error using ./ Matrix dimensions must agree.' However, this worked with input data of length 60, but when I try data of length 1058 it gives me the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that with large dataset it's possible that `find(max(dv)==dv)` will returns multiple numbers. So `OptN` will become a vector, not a scalar.

Then the length of `i` (BTW not a good name for variable in MATLAB, it's also a complex number i) will be unpredictable and probably different from `n` causing the dimension error in the next statement.

You can try `find(max(dv)==dv,1)` instead to get only the first match. Or add a loop.